# How to store data to all users?

Tags: ios, swift, database, save

So here is my view:

### [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApSQp.png)

When I press the button, I want so that the selected item on the pickerview would be saved to all my app users globally. So for example if I select "Green" from the PickerView, I want that every user who uses my app would be able to see cell with the title "Green" on their tableview (after refresing the tab..?). How can I do this?

I thought about usin coredata but can I use it on this instance?

Comment: You need a remote database that stores data off of the client (the phone, in this case). I would recommend Firestore as the first place to look.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, with that I could reload the tableview again. But that is not the thing I was searching for. So, for example I select "Yellow" from the UIPickerView, and than press the button, which adds a cell to the table view with the title "Yellow". What I want is that the same cell would be saved to somewhere and it could be accessed from all devices (= it would show up on every device when they update their view), so it would not be just saved locally to my device.